# Does the Greek concept of "autochthonous" take part in modern discussions of Israel's legitimacy and if so, in what way?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, modern-times, modern-orthodox

I am a bear of very little brains so when I encounter terms drenched in philosophy, I turn to my learned neighbors.

Can someone please use the following word in a sentence that is, to the best of the author's knowledge, "actual factual." I'd be much obliged...

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/autochthonous

Comment: "_Does the Greek concept of 'autochthonous' take part in modern discussions of Israel's legitimacy_... ?" (1) Why need a Greek concept take part in any modern Jewish discussions? Why not _Jewish_ concepts take part in Jewish discussions, of any age? (2) What do you mean by Israel, in "Israel's legitimacy"? The state of Israel? Legitimacy of what? In who's eyes? (The question itself doesn't elaborate an any of these things.)

Comment: The link you bring defines 'autochthonous' as a (fancy?) synonym of 'indigenous' and 'native' (or "formed or originating in the place where found"). Besides the reference to how ancient Athenians viewed themselves, I don't see it as a term "drenched in philosophy", from that link. Are we expected to view ourselves, or other current - or past - inhabitants of the Land of Israel, "as if sprung from the very soil of the region they inhabit[ed]"?